# Looking for a combinatorial solution to a (seemingly) non combinatorial Putnam problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

> **Putnam 1980, problem A4:**
>
> Each of $a, b, c$ are integers and none have an absolute value greater than or equal to one million. Prove that
> $$
> \left| a + b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3\right| > 10^{-21}
> $$
> for any choice of $a, b, c$.

I would have never thought this would have anything to do with combinatorics or the pigeonhole principle but in the book 'Problem solving strategies' by Arthur Engel it's been included in the chapter on the pigeonhole principle. I would give an attempt but I have no idea. I thought about looking at the fractional parts of each of the three terms, but that didn't lead to anything.  If you have a solution please give hints and not the whole solution. Thank you

Comment: Solutions to the old Putnam problems are readily available online, [here](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol804.html) for instance, is this one.

Comment: I'm aware. But none of the 'official' solutions have anything to do with combinatorics

Comment: That *might* mean that combinatorics isn't the most natural means to solve this, no matter what Arthur Engel thinks.

Comment: I know that. But he must have thought of some creative solution to this using combinatorics, which is why he included it in that chapter. I'm looking for that

Comment: The linked solution does use the pigeonhole principle for the second part of the original problem, which you have not included here. Was that second part also omitted from your book?

Comment: No it wasn't omitted. I had solved the second part using pidgeonhole principle already, which is why I didn't include it

Comment: @MNIShaurya Have you looked at the problem and solutions as stated in Arthur Engel? 66a is the "second part" of this problem showing $< 10^{-11} $ which uses PP directly. 66b (which is this problem that use state) uses a different technique similar to kalva. Given how Arthur Engel wrote up the question, I believe his intention is 1) Use PP for that part 2) As an extension, try to find a bound on the other side.